# how to show checkbox with label ? my code display only label why?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, laravel-blade

This is my blade code. Why doesn't it display checkbox:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Enable</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add <label> tag after <input> tag

Comment: It does? https://jsfiddle.net/omeq1pr7/

Comment: may be class `controls` having display:None in your css

Comment: looks like a bootstrap structure? probably make sure that css rules are correct

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `checked` attribute of `HTML`
            just like that

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" <?php if(your_condition) { ?> checked <?php } ?> id="status" value="1">
```